# Como ponerle un evento a una variable de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, eventos

Existe alguna forma de ponerle un evento a una variable de JS, sin usar un setInterval.

Por ejemplo:

```
a = 'asd9'
```

*después de un rato*

```
a = '5as1'
```

el evento quedaría:

```
a.addEventListener('change', ()=>{...})
```

La unica forma que se es poner un setInterval y adentro de ese un if.

Existe alguna forma de no usar eso?

Comment: Las variables no cambian por si solas, algo las hace cambiar, por lo tanto lo que debes locallizar es en que momento o evento esa variable cambia para realizar que lo desees realizar ¿o porque te cambia esa variable?

Comment: Una variable es un término muy extenso. No conozco la forma de hacerlo con strings como el caso que propones. Lo único que sí se puede hacer es monitorear cambios con una variable que guarde valor(es) siendo un objeto por medio de un [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). Pero no sé si la solución de ojbeto te valdrá